# Basecamp3 API Design Issue

Tags: api, basecamp

I just want get an idea how people think about the new API of Basecamp3. We know Basecamp is really a good product for it's simplicity and good UI Design. But when I see the design of Basecamp3 API I just feel lost. Or I am missing something.

Here is the Documentation of Basecamp3 API.

https://github.com/basecamp/bc3-api

And https://github.com/basecamp/bc3-api/blob/master/sections/todos.md

Suppose someone want to show *Todos* on their **APP**. So what is approach?

- Sync all the project
- Then get all todolists/todosets by project [Single API call for every project]
- Then Get todos by todolists/todosets [ Single API call for TodoLists]
- Then check assignee with assignee key

Do you think it will workout for an integrated application. Why we don't have any easy **API end point** where I can provide multiple **project** id, **todolists** and assignee to get **todos**?

Is there anything which I am missing?